# Metorikku- Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /home/hadoopuser/metorikku/examples/movies.yaml

Tags: scala, apache-spark, yaml, filenotfoundexception

I am trying Metorikku -ETL framework for spark .. And I get this error every time I do spark-submit..
I am doing it in a VM ..Can anyone help me please..any work around appreciated

Command I run -spark-submit --class com.yotpo.metorikku.Metorikku /home/hadoopuser/metorikku.jar -c /home/hadoopuser/metorikku/examples/movies.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Metorikku looks for the files in HDFS, so you first have to copy the examples directory there:

```
hdfs dfs -put -f examples /user/hadoop/
```

Then you can run your job as follows:

```
spark-submit --class com.yotpo.metorikku.Metorikku metorikku.jar -c /user/hadoop/examples/movies.yaml
```